# int*string list fsharp

Tags: string, list, f#, int

How would i manipulate the following int*string list to get just the "string" part in a list as my output?

```
let item =[
 (12,"sausages");
 (3,"chips");
 (5,"burger");
 (19,"cheese");
 (24,"milk");
 (44,"eggs");
 ]
```

Ive started with listfilter. Can someone advise how to filter this properly?

Comment: Show us your code with `List.filter`, and where it's going wrong...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simple way:

```
item |> List.map snd
```

Comment: this still returns an int*string list. I just want the words on their own. Is this possible?

Comment: No it doesn't -- it returns a `string list`. Put it into F# interactive or tryfsharp.org and you'll see.

Comment: @user2093122 - This is incorrect.  Please post all code you are running

Answer (score 1):

```
item |> List.map (fun (_, y) -> y)
```

Comment: This just returns an int*string list

Comment: No, it isn't:

> item |> List.map (fun (_, y) -> y);;
val it : string list =
  ["sausages"; "chips"; "burger"; "cheese"; "milk"; "eggs"]

Comment: This is what i get

val item : (int * string) list =
  [(12, "sausages"); (3, "chips"); (5, "burger"); (19, "cheese"); (24, "milk");
   (44, "eggs")]

Comment: And now paste my chunk of code in fsi and look at result... :)

Comment: paste what you're inputting to fsharp. My code refuses to return a string list

Comment: please copy all of your input and output from fsi here

Comment: @rhrahl

let item =[
 (12,"sausages");
 (3,"chips");
 (5,"burger");
 (19,"cheese");
 (24,"milk");
 (44,"eggs");
 ]
item |> List.map (fun (_, y) -> y)

val item : (int * string) list =
  [(12, "sausages"); (3, "chips"); (5, "burger"); (19, "cheese"); (24, "milk");
   (44, "eggs")]

Comment: You should have second line of output - evaluation of List.map. I have no idea why it doesn't show to You. Check it here: http://www.tryfsharp.org/Create